# IndexOutOfBoundsException : Index :0, size: 0 appears when adding an EditText to my android application

Tags: android-studio

I made a `LinearLayout` inside my `ConstraintLayout` and then tried to add an `EditText` but it keeps showing this exception when I try to do anything to that `EditText`, for example, I can't change the width to anything rather than to `wrap_content`.

the Exception:

> java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0   at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)   at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)   at com.android.ninepatch.NinePatchChunk.draw(NinePatchChunk.java:190)   at com.android.ninepatch.NinePatchChunk.draw(NinePatchChunk.java:106)   at android.graphics.BaseCanvas_Delegate$1.draw(BaseCanvas_Delegate.java:464)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.drawInLayer(GcSnapshot.java:697)   at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.GcSnapshot.draw(GcSnapshot.java:587)   at android.graphics.BaseCanvas_Delegate.nDrawNinePatch(BaseCanvas_Delegate.java:461)   at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.nDrawNinePatch(BaseCanvas.java:-1)   at android.graphics.BaseCanvas.drawPatch(BaseCanvas.java:307)   at android.graphics.Canvas.drawPatch(Canvas.java:1825)   at android.graphics.NinePatch.draw(NinePatch.java:217)   at android.graphics.drawable.NinePatchDrawable.draw(NinePatchDrawable.java:249)   at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableContainer.draw(DrawableContainer.java:87)   at android.graphics.drawable.DrawableWrapper.draw(DrawableWrapper.java:240)   at android.view.View.drawBackground(View.java:21671)   at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21435)   at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:56)   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21417)   at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21317)   at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)   at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:4149)   at android.view.View.draw_Original(View.java:21315)   at android.view.View_Delegate.draw(View_Delegate.java:68)   at android.view.View.draw(View.java:21089)   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild_Original(ViewGroup.java:4388)   at android.view.ViewGroup_Delegate.drawChild(ViewGroup_Delegate.java:65)   at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:4388)   at
> .....
> ....

the xml code:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/pink"
    tools:context=".new_post">

    <LinearLayout


        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp">

    </ImageView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="add picture"
        >

    </Button>


        <EditText
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            

            />





    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

How to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

add property background to edittext

```
<EditText 
android:id="@+id/txt_lsmisfromDT"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:focusable="false"
android:background="#ffffff"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add the constraints to the `LinearLayout` to be like that

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/pink"
    tools:context=".new_post">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/myimage"
        android:layout_width="270dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:text="add picture" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

When you omit these constraints, the android doesn't know the bounds of your `LinearLayout` even though you put the `layout_width` to match_parent.

**Note** If you have just one `ViewGroup` like the `LinearLayout` inside another `ViewGroup` you should remove one of them. what i mean is that in this example you should remove either the `ConstraintLayout` or the `LinearLayout`.